# Issue with dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

i have a problem with the **SelectedIndexChanged** event of dropdownlist,
on the page load i am checking for the id and make that item selected in the dropdownlist.
now on the **SelectedIndexChanged** of the dropdownlist, when i try the print, **dropdownlist.SelectedValue**, it returns me blank value, i guess the thing on the page load for the dropdownlist defautl selected value is messing me up, but still that is required.

Below is my Page Load Code:-

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ListItem item = ddlslideslist.Items.FindByValue(bl.SlideShowId.ToString());
    if (item != null) item.Selected = true;
}
```

and below is the code under SelectedIndexChanged Event.

```
Response.Write(ddlslideslist.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Are you in Visual Studio? Add a breakpoint and watch `ddlslideslist` to find out which item it thinks is selected.

Comment: Have you disabled ViewState on the page?  Where do you bind the data to the control in the context of the Page_Load code?

Comment: how are you binding your data?